# Multiple Identical IPv4 NICs under Linux?

Tags: linux-networking, local-area-network

Is it possible to have multiple network interfaces, **each identically configured**, on the same Linux machine?

For example, four different NICs, each looking at physically separate networks 192.168.44.0, configured to be 192.168.44.1, net-mask 255.255.255.0. Talking to static IP addresses via TCP or UDP (no DHCP).

We can't specify that they be 169.254/16 like [RFC 3927](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927) discusses. I think we can assume that nodes with the same IP addresses on these different physical networks will all have unique MAC addresses.

It seems like the network stack's routing would be broken, right? Are there standard tools/methods to implement this? (iptables?)

Are there any open source projects or products designed to make this work and/or help keep things straight? Know anyone who's tried this?

We're prepared to write some custom code to pull it off, if need be.

Does RFC 3927 hold the key? Seems close, but not quite.

Does this Q belong on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: Is this for load balancing/link aggregation purposes?

Comment: have you considered putting some sort of proxy server/gateway on each physical network with a 192.168.44.1 interface and another interface configured more conventionally to talk to the 4-nic machine?

Comment: @BrandonXavier We want to minimize the number of components, particularly if all we really need is a NIC.  For a one-off, this might have been the way to go.

Comment: @slightly_toasted its for dealing with some equipment in a vertical market that the mfr never envisioned aggregating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible, it can be done with network [namespaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-netns.8.html)

Each interface can have an identical configuration on the same machine, however they would all have to be separated into individual namespaces.

```
   A network namespace is logically another copy of the network stack,
   with its own routes, firewall rules, and network devices.

   By default a process inherits its network namespace from its parent.
   Initially all the processes share the same default network namespace
   from the init process.
```

Comment: This is amazing, thank you! Very sorry I can only give it one upvote.